# Can we store files on the django framework?

Tags: python, django, excel, automation

I was wondering on how to store some files in the django framework, and how to access them for editing and updating them? I wanted to upload a few excel files and a few python scripts which automate the excel files. Everything is working fine locally for me, but just wanted to know on how to do it for webpage which can be accessed by anyone?

Thanks

Comment: You could use the standard `open` function to manipulate the file. Remember that the file path may vary across different environments. To handle changing file paths you could take the help of BASE_DIR variable in settings: `from django.conf import settings; settings.BASE_DIR`

Comment: I think I am not getting the question right.
Are you finding issues in uploading files to the app server that is running django?
Or Are you finding difficulties in running the python code that edits excel sheets from django app?
Or Are you unsure of how to edit excel files from django app code?

Comment: I am finding difficulties in running the python code that edits excel sheets from django app which should run when a html button is clicked on the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Copy the python automation code under your app directory, import it as a module in your django `view.py` file and call the function that performs the specified task. (preferred)

```
<your_app>/
├── admin.py
├── ...
├── <your_automation_script>.py
└── views.py
```

```py
# views.py
from .<your_automation_script> import <edit_xlsx>

def view_function(req):
    # ... do before xls edition ...
    <edit_xlsx>()
    # ... do after xls edition ...
    return "something"
```

2. Create a subprocess of the python automation code in the django view. (not preferred)

```py
# views.py
import subprocess

def view_function(req):
    # ... do before xls edition ...
    process = subprocess.run(['/path/to/automation_script.py','<args_if_any>'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

    output = process.stdout
    errors = process.stderr
    # ... do after xls edition ...
    return "something"
```

Comment: I have used the preferred method, the excel files are in a separate folder in the app directory, it throws me an error 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testcase_database.xlsx'. 

In the automation code I used from excel.testcase import * to import the files into the script. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to provide the absolute path (such as `/var/www/static/testcase_database.xlsx`) to the xlsx file, in the python automation code.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now! But how do we access those excel files now from the webpage? These files can be checked by my in my local system, how would you do it via the webpage

Comment: Ensure that your excel file is in one of the static files directory. You can then access the excel file like any other static file (such as js,css,jpg etc)